# using ei_decode_list when decoding a nested list of elements

Tags: c++, erlang

I have a nested list of the form,

```
{stack, "over", flow, ["is", "a"], ["knowledge", "sharing", "site"], "a", "b"}
```

I am not able to cleanly decode the above tuple. I decode the above into a

```
 vector<vector<string> >
```

However, If I replace the inner lists into a tuple, I am able to decode that fine. I doubt that the usage of ERL_NIL_EXT and ERL_LIST_EXT but the documentation is only a little helpful.

Idea is if I get list inside my tuple, I am decoding that and returning a vector of strings and do walk the tuple linearly. But I am not sure whats wrong. Help!

Code:

```
vector< vector<string> > decode_tuple(char *buff)
{
  vector< vector<string> > decoded_tuple;
  int index = 0;
  int size;
  int res = ei_decode_tuple_header(buff, &index, &size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    int entry_size;
    int type;
    int res = ei_get_type(buff, &index, &type, &entry_size);
    char *decoded_val = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (entry_size + 1));
    switch (type)
    {
        case ERL_ATOM_EXT:
        {
            vector<string> value;
            ei_decode_atom(buff, &index, decoded_val);
            cout<<decoded_val<<endl;
            value.push_back(decoded_val);
            decoded_tuple.push_back(value);
            free(decoded_val);
            break;
        }
        case ERL_STRING_EXT:
        {
            vector<string> value;
            ei_decode_string(buff, &index, decoded_val);
            cout<<decoded_val<<endl;
            value.push_back(decoded_val);
            decoded_tuple.push_back(value);
            free(decoded_val);
            break;
        }
        case ERL_SMALL_TUPLE_EXT:
        case ERL_LARGE_TUPLE_EXT:
        {
            pair<int, vector<string> > value;
            value = decode_inner_tuple(buff, index);
            index = value.first;
            decoded_tuple.push_back(value.second);
            break;
        }
        case ERL_NIL_EXT:
        {
            vector<string> value;
            ei_decode_string(buff, &index, decoded_val);
            free(decoded_val);
            break;
        }
        case ERL_LIST_EXT:
        {
            pair<int, vector<string> > value;
            value = decode_inner_list(buff, index);
            index = value.first;
            decoded_tuple.push_back(value.second);
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout<<"Not a valid string"<<endl;
            break;
     }
   }
  return decoded_tuple;
 }

pair<int, vector<string> > decode_inner_list(char *buff, int index)
{
 vector<string> decoded_list;
 int size;
 int res = ei_decode_list_header(buff, &index, &size);
 for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
 {
    int entry_size;
    int type;
    int res = ei_get_type(buff, &index, &type, &entry_size);
    if(type == ERL_STRING_EXT)
    {
        char *decoded_value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (entry_size + 1));
        ei_decode_string(buff, &index, decoded_value);
        decoded_list.push_back(decoded_value);
        free(decoded_value);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not a valid string" << endl;
        break;
    }
 }
 return make_pair(index, decoded_list);
};
```

Comment: Providing a [mcve] might be useful. There is `break` missing from `case ERL_NIL_EXT` but it is probably something that doesn't cause the problem.

Comment: edited. yes, I dont think that it was the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you handle `ERL_NIL_EXT`. That type represents an empty list, which means it's composed of just a list header with no elements. To decode it, just decode a list header:

```
case ERL_NIL_EXT:
    ei_decode_list_header(buff, &index, &entry_size);
    break;
```